# jQuery selecting and filtering elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, css-selectors

I have a problem with selecting and filtering elements inside a div.

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" value="you can edit me">
    <input type="button" value="click me">
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$("#wrapper").children().click(function() {
    alert("hi there");
});
```

The problem is I get alerted every time I click anything inside the div.
But my requirement is to alert only when the user clicks on the button.
I know that filtering the elements in jQuery is using `:button`

This is what I have tried :

```
$("#wrapper").children(":button").click(function() {
    alert("hi there");
});
```

and

```
$("#wrapper").children().filter(":button").click(function() {
    alert("hi there");
});
```

It didn't work

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @Erwin - for future reference, avoid checking the "Community Wiki" checkbox when posting questions like this. This is a valid programming question and users should earn rep from it

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
$("#wrapper input[type=button]").click(function() {
    alert("hi there");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use id for a specific button-

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" value="you can edit me">
    <input type="button" id='btnMyButton' value="click me">
    <input type="button" class='btnClass' id='btnMyButton2' value="click me 2">
<input type="button" class='btnClass' id='btnMyButton3' value="click me 3">
</div>

$('#btnMyButton').click(function(){
alert("hi there");
});
```

For all buttons in the div, follow John's answer. Use class for some buttons-

```
$('.btnClass').click(function(){
    alert("all class");
});
```

btw, i like to put my all jquery function inside ready function like-

```
$(document).ready(function(){        

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

`$("#wrapper :button").click(function() {
    alert("I love Imogen Poots");
});`

See [this](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#wrapper > input[type=button]").click(function() {
    alert("hi there");
});
```