# How can I insert mulitple rows in table at once in MVC asp .net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new at MVC asp .net.

I have a grid in which I am adding rows.

Now I  want to perform mulitple rows insertion in a table at once.
How can I do that. SO multiple rows will be added in MVC.

Any help would be appericiated.

Comment: When you say Grid, what are you referring to?  A third party, or an extension, or just a table, what specifically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding into a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058632/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-into-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

You want to learn how to ModelBind to a Collection.  There are many answers here already for this technique.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=model+binding+to+a+collection

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?.

```
 <table class="table" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.title)
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.imgAr)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.created)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tblOfContent">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <img src="~/newsImages/@item.imgAr" class="img-thumbnail" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.created.ToShortDateString()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Edit", new { id = item.id }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.id }) 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and in the Controller something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(newsService.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.created));
    }
```