# In an ASP.NET MVC 3 view, how can I generate an editor for a list field?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a form in an ASP.NET MVC 3 view, in which one field is to specify a list of ints (corresponding to `List<int>` in the edited model). How can I generate this editor field in my view? I assume there are MVC 3 helpers I can make use of.

Comment: You're talking about a List<Int32> in your model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding into a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058632/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-into-a-list)

Comment: @SteenT Sorry I needed to escape the angle brackets :)

Comment: There're dozens of similar questions. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+model+binding+to+list

Comment: @archil As far as I can tell the first question at least pertains to model binding towards the controller, while I am basically asking how to create a model editor in the view.

Comment: @archil Looking at the questions returned by your search, I can't see any that answer my question. I think you are basically misunderstanding what I'm asking, since it isn't about model binding (towards the controller), but model editing (towards the view).

Comment: @aknuds case is that generally those answers involve  both controller and view sides. From the exact duplicate question's accepted answer, Scott Hanselman says: you don’t need the bracket notation if you’re submitting simple types. That is, if your request contains key=foo&key=bar&key=baz, we’ll correctly bind that to an IEnumerable<T>, IList<T>, ICollection<T>, T[], Collection<T>, or List<T>.  In the first sentence in this paragraph, "simple type" means a type for which TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)) returns true.This makes a handful of cases simpler.

Comment: I'm currently prototyping a solution with just a textbox in which the user enters integers with spaces between them, then I'll use Javascript to parse the text as a list.

Comment: That is not the solution i would reccomend. Asp.net mvc has that feature built in, and you need it every time. Really not the best part there to reinvent.

Comment: @archil Do you mind explaining what I'm reinventing? I haven't so far found an alternative to the textbox input, and I'm going to do client-side validation (through unobtrusive JavaScript) anyway. Furthermore, the form data are submitted by JavaScript (it's part of Comet functionality).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got totally confused by tags :). Generally, this has nothing to do with asp.net mvc.

Comment: @archil Well, I was hoping I could use an MVC helper method (like Html.EditorFor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a dropdownlist you can use the HTML.DropDownList helper method. Is this what you want or do you need to display the List as an Ordered/Unordered HTML list?

### EDIT

You can create your own HTML Helper function. Assuming you use Razor you can follow the following steps

1.)Create a new .cshtml file inside App_Code directory and name it as you want (for example HTMLHelpers.cshtml)

2.)Write the following in the file

```
@helper OrderedList(List<int> list) {
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in list)
        {
            <li>@item</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

3.)Now in your view you can call your new function. For example write

```
@HTMLHelpers.OrderedList(Model)
```

### 2nd EDIT

You can also use Javascript to achieve that functionality. [Knockout.js](http://www.knockoutjs.com) from Steven Sanderson is a great library that helps you to databind values to html elements.

[This sample](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/simpleList.html) from knockout.js documentation is similar to your needs.

You can also view [this blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) from Steven Sanderson that explains how to use Knockout.js with a variable length list and how to submit the list data back to server.

Comment: The list is initially empty, and the user should add elements to it in the form. I doubt dropdownlist is suitable for this purpose (I'm an HTML newb)?

Comment: How does this let the user add elements to an initially empty list?

Comment: You have to create that functionality in your view. For example add a textbox and a button that Post the form to the controller. The controller then should add the value to the list (model) and redisplay the view with the new model.

Comment: You can also use Javascript to achieve that functionality. See [Knockout.JS](http://knockoutjs.com/) which is a great library

Comment: My whole question is really how to create the editor, preferably it should be generated by an ASP.NET MVC helper. I see you suggest a textbox; that's fairly primitive, but I'm trying the same thing right now since I haven't received any more suitable suggestions.

Comment: Knockout.JS looks more like it. I found a list widget that does what I need. Is there a jQuery UI equivalent (since I'm already using this framework)?

Comment: Can you post the list widget you found?

Comment: Ok. KnockoutJs is a javascript framework that allows you to databind elements. It is totaly different to JQuery UI. You can use both of them as they have different functionality.

Comment: I suggest you post an answer pertaining to the Knockout.js list widget (update this answer?).

Comment: I believe this post from Steven Sanderson (the creator of Knockout.js) will help you. [Editing a Variable length list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/)

Comment: If you write this in your answer (as opposed to the comments section), I'll accept it :)

Comment: Done. I hope that I helped ;)

Comment: I can't say for sure that I'll use this widget (I might), but you helped my understanding a great deal anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

[Phil Haack's blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) discusses every aspect of using model binding to a list: controller code, view code, complex and primitive types, dictionary binding. From the first paragraph of that blog post, MVC builtin model binder binds List with just passing number of same named query string (or form when posting) parameters to controller. Example

```
<form method="get">
   <input type="checkbox" name="ints" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="ints" value="4" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="ints" value="2" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="ints" value="8" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This would bind correctly to

```
public ActionResult UpdateInts(List<int> ints) {

  return View(ints);
}
```

See that blog post for the complete information

Comment: The blog post is really only helpful in understanding how to convert form fields to a single list in the controller. Since the post only shows how to create a form for a list of fixed size, it's not of much help in my case (my list is initially empty and the user should populate it).

Comment: @aknuds1 I'm in doubt anyone will write complete programs for you, on StackOverflow at least. To achieve full program-wide list model binding in asp.net MVC, fisrt you need to understand model binding to a list. That's what the blog post is about. Now, go ahead - use some javascript to make that static form dynamic. Try it, and update your question with the problems you encounter. Than people can help you.

Comment: I'm specifically not asking about model binding towards the controller, I'm only interested in the editor part (in the view). GeoChatz has posted an interesting (partial?) solution (Knockout.js). The JavaScript is irrelevant for the question; I said I'm going with a textbox for now, but I'd like something designed for list input.